# Switching branches in Git with external dependencies

Tags: git, maven, dependencies, git-branch

Has anyone had to deal with the issues of switching git branches in a project that has Maven (or any other external) dependencies? For example, suppose that in one branch I have a maven dependency, and in another I don't (or have a different version required). Would I have to re-import maven dependencies each time I switch branches or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends on an IDE you're using. I haven't noticed any issue with this when using IntelliJ IDEA. It handles any `pom.xml` changes on the filesystem level very smoothly.

However, some time ago, when I was using Eclipse, I believe I saw such a problem you're talking about. Then there was a need for reimporting Maven projects to have the IDE aware of Maven model changes. I'm not sure how mature is Eclipse support for Maven nowadays though.

Comment: It shouldn't be IDE specific, maven can be run on the command line for importing dependencies (afaik). Same would go for node / npm dependencies

Comment: Of course command line Maven run is clearly stateless, meaning it always starts with `pom.xml` parsing and running what it found there. When you named *reimporting* what you're doing, I assumed you're asking about IDE stuff since IDEs do caching, parsing understanding of Maven project model on their own, without running native Maven under the hood constantly. In terms of clear Maven, there no such thing like *importing* or *reimporting* dependencies. There is just `pom.xml` that has to be read and run.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Recently I've seen now that (with automatic importing on) switching branches doesn't always trigger a huge re-parsing of the pom's